# Increase the power in an induction heater

Tags: power-supply, inverter, resonance, induction, self-induction

I am working on an induction heater of 3 kilowatt. I want to increase the power upto 5 kilowatt. What should I do?

I have built  zero voltage switching type induction heater. I used a 3uf capacitor and 6 turns of copper tube, diameter of 2 inches and 4 IGBTs.

Should I increase the frequency with respect to L and C?

Four years ago ,I had made HCR based Series resonant Induction Furnace of 2.5kW .It was very simple frequency generate through any 555 ic and power of induction controlled by output current transformer which is in series of tank circuit and secondary voltage convert into dc by the bridge rectifier then this voltage gives to pin no.5 of Control voltage pin , so frequency of the circuit is under-controlled some time it kill the HCR so I left the work . I am doing work on IGBT with arduino. I have search lots of site regarding still i didn't find the related source

[image]

Comment: Did you purchase the induction heater, or you have built it?  You have no information in your question. Nothing about your coil nor capacitors. Neither have you provided anything about the induction generator.

Comment: I have build the ZVS type Induction Heater, I have used 3uf capacitor and 6 turn of copper tube , diameter of 2 inch and 4 IGBT.

Comment: Add the information to your question by editing the question, not in comment section. The more information you provide, you will get more and better answers here.

Comment: Ma'am ,4 years ago ,I had made HCR based Series resonant Induction Furnace of 2.5kW .It was very simple frequency generate through any 555 ic  and power of induction controlled by output current transformer which is in series of tank circuit and secondary voltage convert into dc by the bridge rectifier then this voltage gives to pin no.5 of Control voltage pin , so frequency of the circuit is under-controlled some time it   kill the HCR so I left the work . I am doing work on IGBT with arduino. I have search lots of site regarding still i didn't find the related source

Comment: It will be great if I work under you. Kindly show the path

Comment: Add all the relevant technical info to the question.

Comment: I don't see how this circuit can possibly work, as there's no way to turn the MOSFET back off after you've turned it on.